# How to show that $(\mathbb{Z}[x], +, \cdot)$ is a ring?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Show that $(\mathbb{Z}[x], +, \cdot)$ is a ring and that $1 \notin
>  (\{x, x+2 \})$

Any ideas how to attack this problem? I'm also interested about the second part of the question that $1$ doesn't belong there.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner I assume one can show that something is a ring by showing that it actually satisfies the properties of a ring. But what about the second part?

Comment: For the first question, see [Polynomial ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring).

Comment: @pandora: To show that something is a ring there really is no other way then showing that it satisfies the properties of a ring. For the second part try to write $1$ as $1 = p(x)x + q(x)(x+2)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Degree actually isn't enough, as this statement is false for $x+1$ instead of $x+2$

Comment: @StellaBiderman You are right of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your comment, yes. You just have to check that the ring axioms hold.

For the second, assume $f(x)x+g(x)(x+2)=1$. Then $(f(x)+g(x))x+2g(x)=1$. The LHS clearly has an even constant term, contradiction.